# Go - SignatureDoesNotMatch error when S3 object name contains "="

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

i am struggling with using the s3manager to create files on S3.
the file names need to be in the following format "set=2012-04-3", containing an "=".
uploading with out the "=" works perfectly...

code:

```golang
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

_, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("/testbucket/data/set=2012-04-3/"),
    Key:    aws.String("test.json"),
    Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte(message.Body)),
})

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\n Error: There was an issue uploading to s3: %s \n", err.Error())
}
```

Would be grateful for any help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will post the answer here in case someone else needs it.

```html
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

_, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("/testbucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("/data/set=2012-04-3/test.json"),
    Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte(message.Body)),
})

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("\n Error: There was an issue uploading to s3: %s \n", err.Error())
}
```

the Bucket could not contain a path

Answer (score 0):

Equals sign (=) should be *URL encoded or referenced as HEX*. See AWS S3 documentation for more info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html